# Get real name of method defined in IDL in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, com, idl, enumerator

We have project with IDL and there is defined interface with Enumeration. It has property with ID = DISPID_NEWENUM (support for for-each etc.).

From this we generate interop dll. When I use reflection to get all methods of that interface, this method is replaced with GetEnumerator method.

Can I get true name (which is written in IDL) of method somehow with reflection?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: If it is not _NewEnum then send a nasty email to the author.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by retrieving `TypeInfo` instance for your type, and reading the name of method marked with DISPID_NEWENUM dispid. Here's an example:

```
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;

  var tiPtr = Marshal.GetITypeInfoForType(typeof (IMyInterface));
  var ti = (ITypeInfo)Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(tiPtr);

  string[] names = new string[1];
  int cnt;
  ti.GetNames(-4, names, 1, out cnt); // -4 = DISPID_NEWENUM
  // string[0] == "_NewEnum"
```

`ITypeInfo` gives you the access to all the metadata of the type, e.g. you can read member documentation (if available in type library) etc.

Comment: I have little problems with your advice. GetTypeInfo is C++ function, but I'm writing my app in C#. Second problem is in GetIDispatchForObject - I don't have object, I have just Type (the interface). So I don't know how to use functions you suggest. :(

Comment: WRT C++/C#, `GetTypeInfo` is not a C++ function, it's a method on `IDispatch` interface. Have you checked the last link from my answer? WRT to instance/type can you create a dummy instance? You can also open the type library with `LoadTypeLibEx` API but that is more work.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't create dummy instance. I have just those interfaces.

Comment: I got exception: Typelib export: Type library is not registered. 
I have solved it by parsing IDL files. Which is not best solution, but it's working ;)

Comment: well, of course that typelib must be registered, otherwise it is not possible to find the data. I took this for granted, as you go IDL->interop dll, which means that there is typelib in the middle somewhere.